# Real number in while loop in bash

Tags: bash

I would like to do a while loop in bash, using real numbers, but it always gives me errors. Whatever I try and find on the internet it doesn't fix the problem.

Here is the problematic part of my code: (energy is find with a command like energy=$(echo "$real1 - $real2" | bc -l)

```
energy=${energy#-}
deltaE=$(echo "$energy"  | bc -l)
echo $energy
echo $deltaE

while (( $deltaE > 0.0001 ));
do
```

Of course there is something after "do" but the execution stops here. This gives me the following error :

```
1.999655175151897025
1.999655175151897025
./run_ILDA.sh: line 99: ((: 1.999655175151897025 > 0.0001 : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".999655175151897025 > 0.0001 ")
```

And without the $ :

```
while (( deltaE > 0.0001 ));
do
```

It gives

```
1.999655175151897025
1.999655175151897025
./run_ILDA.sh: line 99: ((: 1.999655175151897025: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".999655175151897025")
```

I also tried with :

```
while [  $deltaE -gt 0.0001 ]
do
```

And this gives me :

```
1.999655175151897025
1.999655175151897025
./run_ILDA.sh: line 99: [: 1.999655175151897025: integer expression expected
```

Does someone know what's going on and how to fix this?

Comment: Bash doesn't do floating point numbers. Use bc or awk.

Comment: But I used bc to compute $energy and $deltaE, so it should work no?

Comment: No, bash doesn't accept floats, no matter how you made them.

Comment: `bc` *internally* deals with floats; there's nothing special about the string it outputs that makes `bash` capable of treating it as a float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use bc to evaluate the comparison:

```
if (( $(echo "$deltaE > 0.0001" | bc -l) )); then
    ...
fi
```